# wpf register dependecy of another control

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a canvas and I want to create a dependency property and set it to the scroll view which is the parent control of the canvas. I get a dependecy error

> Exception thrown: 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' in PresentationFramework.dll

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Grid>
        <ScrollViewer Name="NexusScrollViewer"
                                  Background="Transparent"
                                  HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                                  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
            <nexus:NexusCanvas x:Name="MyDesignerCanvas"
                                          MinHeight="800"
                                          MinWidth="800"
                                          AllowDrop="True"
                                          ScrollViewer="{Binding ElementName=NexusScrollViewer}"
                                          Background="#FF252629">
                <Ellipse Canvas.Left="50" Canvas.Top="200" Fill="Red" Width="100" Height="100"/>
                <Ellipse Canvas.Left="200" Canvas.Top="10" Fill="LightBlue" Width="100" Height="100"/>
            </nexus:NexusCanvas>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
```

**NexusCanvas.cs**

```
public class NexusCanvas : Canvas
    {
        private Point? dragStartPoint = null;


        // attempt to combine scrollview and canvas into one
        public ScrollViewer ScrollViewer
        {
            get { return (ScrollViewer)GetValue(ScrollViewerProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ScrollViewerProperty, value); }
        }
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ScrollViewerProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("ScrollViewer", typeof(ScrollViewer), typeof(ScrollViewer));

    }
```

Would i be better of just finding the parent of canvas when i create the control in the NexusCanvas.cs, if so how would i do that?

Comment: Try DependencyProperty.Register("ScrollViewer", typeof(ScrollViewer), typeof(NexusCanvas), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `NexusCanvas` in the `typeof` for the third parameter.

```
public class NexusCanvas : Canvas
{
    private Point? dragStartPoint = null;


    // attempt to combine scrollview and canvas into one
    public ScrollViewer ScrollViewer
    {
        get { return (ScrollViewer)GetValue(ScrollViewerProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ScrollViewerProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ScrollViewerProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ScrollViewer", typeof(ScrollViewer), typeof(NexusCanvas));
}
```

Comment: do i still keep the bit above it? as well?

Comment: Yes, you need everything.

Comment: Please mark it as answer then </endofshamelessreppursuit> :)